# Extract contents between two tags

Tags: regex

I have a simple HTML string. From that string I would like to extract the contents BETWEEN two HTML tags.

My source string is this:

```
"Hello <b>world</b> test"
```

I would like to extract: "world"

How do I do that?

Comment: we need to know what language you're using this regex in.  Regular expressions are used to identify text.  moreover, your example has NOTHING to do with your actual question.  see this question about html extraction http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1178921

Comment: The definitive answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/85371

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't mean *any*  tag, but a specific tag (in this case `<b>`), and assuming that your HTML is well-formed and thus doesn't contain nested `<b>` tags:

```
(?s)<b[^>]*>((?:(?!</b>).)*)</b>
```

The result will be in group number 1.

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)       # Allow the dot to match newlines (hope you're not using JavaScript)
<b[^>]*>   # Match opening <b> tag
(          # Capture the following:
 (?:       #  Match (and don't capture)...
  (?!      #   (as long as we're not at the start of
    </b>   #    the string </b>
  )        #   )
  .        #  any character.
 )*        #  Repeat any number of times
)          # End of capturing group.
</b>       # Match closing </b> tag
```

Answer (score -1):

While this might be possible in extremely simple contexts, I'd strongly recommend against it. Regexp is not powerful enough to parse HTML. Use a proper HTML parsing library.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what language you're using, this is a VB.NET example:

the pattern would be "hello (.*) test"

and the Regex.Matches function would take your input and pattern and return a collection of matches. Each match would contain groups, group 0 would be the whole match: "hello world test" and group 1 would be the text inside the group: "world"

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("hello world test", "hello (.+) test").Item(0).Groups(1)

And like Dervall said Regex might not be powerful enough for what you want to do and you might need heavy modification of the pattern to work with HTML, like making white space (spaces, tabs, and new lines) optional as 1 example.

Comment: Check the edit - the tags had gotten lost due to bad formatting.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the following expression which will also validate that the end tag matches the beginning tag.

```
(?<=<(b)>)[^>]+(?=</\1>)
```

A more "digestible" example would be:

```
(?<=<(b)>)[^>]+(?=</b>)
```